# Foundation, simple form, text area, columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form, zurb-foundation

I have a Zurb Foundation simple form with one field (:description) being a text area.  I want the text area to be 10 rows deep but it appears as 2 rows.  Anyone know how to change this?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-4 large-centered columns">
    <%= simple_form_for(@venue) do |f| %>
      <fieldset>
        <%= f.input :name %>
        <%= f.input :url %>
        <%= f.input :street %>
        <%= f.input :city %>
        <%= f.input :state %>
        <%= f.input :description, as: :text, :input_html => { :cols => 5, :rows => 10 } %>
        <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "button small radius" %>
      </fieldset>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Since you are using bootstrap, default properties of bootstrap applies to your input textarea. It causes the problem. I had the same problem but, with columns.

You can overcome this problem by two solutions:

1.) Create a class and specify the height and width to be auto. Use the class wherever required.

Create this class in your application.css or any css file.

```
.test
{
width: auto;
height: auto;
}
```

Now use this class in your ruby code.

```
 <%= f.input :description, as: :text, :input_html => { class: 'test', :cols => 5, :rows => 10 } %>
```

Since you have explicitly specified the width and height to be auto, the bootstrap's textarea width, height will be overrided by the local class **'test'** width and height.
Hence :cols => 5, :rows => 10 properties will be set.

2.) Modify the input textarea properties in your bootstrap css file.
Change the height or width of input textarea to auto to avoid confusions or set it to a standard pixel if you are going to use the same width and height everywhere.

Comment: actually, that causes my text area to be half the width of its container.

Comment: Modifying the bootstrap css(setting width and height to auto) will by default make all the textarea to be half the width of your container. Because it explicitly ignores the default bootstrap css definition. Try the first solution. So that you will always use the default bootstrap properties and for certain cases you can override it by specifying the class explicitly as shown in solution 1.

Comment: I am using step #1.  I don't put a :cols attribute and my :description is half the width of my container.

Comment: So uncomment width to be auto in your new class. So that it 'll take the default bootstrap width n hence your text area will not be half of the container. In the above scenario I have overrided both width n height of bootstrap. In ur case u can do height alone.. Ex: .test{height:auto;}

Comment: FWIW, the OP is using Zurb Foundation, not Bootstrap. But the solution is the same.

Answer (score 5):

the class assignment doesn't work , try this instead

```
=f.input :description, label: false, :as => :text, :input_html => { :rows => 7 , :style => 'width: 100%'}
```

Works gre8 for me.!